# an error in caffe train

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

everybody.I'd like to use caffe to train a 5 classes detection task with "SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector", so I changed the num_classes from 21 to 6.However,I get an following error:

"**Check failed: num_priors_ * num_classes_ == bottom[1]->channels() (52392 vs. 183372) Number of priors must match number of confidence predictions.**"

I can understand this error,and I found 52392/6=183372/21,namely why I changed num_classes to 6,but the number of confidence predictions is still 183372. So how to solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do your labels contain only 5 classes?

Comment: @malreddysid  yes,maybe the number of confidence predictions is definited by the author,so it is not well for me,so how to solve the problem, I only want to train a 5 classes model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SSD depends on the number of labels not only for the classification output, but also for the BB prediction, you would need to change `num_output` in several other places in the model.
I would strongly suggest you wouldn't do that manually, but rather use the python scripts provided in the `'examples/ssd'` folder. For instance, you can change [line 277 in `'examples/ssd/ssd_pascal_speed.py'`](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/examples/ssd/ssd_pascal_speed.py#L277) to:

```
num_classes = 5 # instead of 21
```

And then use the model files this script provides.

Comment: Great thanks to you.I found the author LiuWei said " Add conf_postfix="_whatever_you_like" in CreatMultiBoxHead of ssd_pascal.py ". However, windows caffe is compiled with VS,so the ssd_pascal.py can't work,and I'd like to modify the file for windows

Comment: @H.Hao once you run the python script you'll have all the prototxt files (train, test and solver) created for you with the appropriate `num_output`. The you can use these files to run caffe manually.